Evaluate infinitely nested function call $f(f(f(....)))$
It's been awhile since I took Calc 1 and I am reviewing it. I came across this problem.

Let $x_{1} = 100$. For all integers $n$, let $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(x_{n} + \frac{100}{x_{n}})$. Assume that
$\lim_{n \to \infty}(x_{n}) = L$, and calculate $L$.

It reminds me of some sort of compound interest problem but I can't figure out how to match this pattern with the compound interest formula.
The problem is supposed to be able to be solved with basic limit theorems that you learn about at the beginning of Calc 1. I imagine we have to find some way to rewrite the formula for $x_{n+1}$ in terms of $n$ rather than in terms of $x_{n}$. Then we can take the limit like normal. The problem is that I don't know how to do that.
Nevertheless, I can solve this problem with an overcomplicated and messy proof which probably contains a few oversights and logical leaps.
Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(x + \frac{100}{x}\right)$. I'll wager that there exists some $c$ such that if $c < x$ then $c < f(x) < x$. First I will show that there exists some $c$ such that if $c < x$ then $f(x) < x$.
$$c < x$$
$$c^2 < x^2$$
$$\frac{c^2}{x} < x$$
$$x + \frac{c^2}{x} < 2x$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(x + \frac{c^2}{x}\right) < x$$
$$\text{let } c = \pm 10$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(x + \frac{(\pm 10)^2}{x}\right) < x$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(x + \frac{100}{x}\right) < x$$
$$f(x) < x$$
We have found possible values for $c$, which are $10$ and $-10$. Now I will show that, with at least one of the values of $c$ I found in the previous part, it is also true that if $c < x$ then $c < f(x)$.
$$\text{If } c = -10 \text{, then}$$
$$-10 < x$$
$$\text{suppose } x = -5$$
$$f(-5) = \frac{1}{2}\left(5 + \frac{100}{5}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(5 + 20\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(25\right) = -12.5$$
$$-10 < -12.5 \text{ is false}$$
$$\text{so } c \ne -10$$
$$\text{If } c = 10 \text{, then}$$
$$10 < x$$
$$10 (10x - 100) < x (10x - 100)$$
$$100x - 1000 < 10x^2 - 100x$$
$$100x + 100x < 10x^2 + 1000$$
$$x(100 + 100) < 10(x^2 + 100)$$
$$\frac{100 + 100}{10} < \frac{x^2 + 100}{x}$$
$$10 + \frac{100}{10} < x + \frac{100}{x}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}(10 + \frac{100}{10}) < \frac{1}{2}(x + \frac{100}{x})$$
$$f(10) < f(x)$$
$$10 < f(x)$$
$$c < f(x)$$
So to recap, we have that if $10 < x$ then $f(x) < x$, and also that if $10 < x$ then $10 < f(x)$. We can combine these two statements together to say that if $10 < x$ then $10 < f(x) < x$.
Given that $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and some initial $x_{1} > 10$, we can define $x_{n + 1} = f(x_{n})$ . By our previous conclusion, for any $x_{n}$, $10 < f(x_{n}) < x_{n}$, or in other words, $10 < x_{n + 1} < x_{n}$. We could also say that $10 < x_{a} < x_{b}$ if $a > b$. Intuitively, it seems that as $n$ tends to infinity, $x_{n}$ tends to $10$. Or in other words, that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(x_{n}) = 10$. Now I need to prove it.
Given any $\epsilon > 0$, I want to show that there exists an integer $M$ given by $10 < x_{M} < 10 + \epsilon$. For the case that $x_{1} \le 10 + \epsilon$, we can just set $M = 1$, easy. But for the case that $x_{1} > 10 + \epsilon$, it's a bit more complicated. I will first assume that there exists no integer $M$ such that $10 < x_{M} < 10 + \epsilon$. In other words, for any integer $n$, if $x_{n} > 10 + \epsilon$, then $10 + \epsilon < x_{n + 1} < x_{n}$. But then this implies that if we want to find $c$ such that if $x > c$ then $c < f(x) < x$, then we could find $10 + \epsilon$ as a possible solution for $c$. But this is clearly false, since earlier we found that there was only one solution for $c$ and it was $10$, not some $10 + \epsilon$. With our assumption contradicted, the opposite of our assumption must be true. Therefore, there is some integer $M$ such that $10 < x_{M} < 10 + \epsilon$.
Now with our value of $M$, we want to show that if $n > M$, then $\lvert x_{n} - 10 \rvert < \epsilon$.
$$n > M$$
$$10 < x_{n} < x_{M}$$
$$0 < x_{n} - 10 < x_{M} - 10$$
$$-(x_{M} - 10) < 0 < x_{n} - 10 < x_{M} - 10$$
$$-(x_{M} - 10) < x_{n} - 10 < x_{M} - 10$$
$$-\epsilon < -(x_{M} - 10) < x_{n} - 10 < x_{M} - 10 < \epsilon$$
$$-\epsilon < x_{n} - 10 < \epsilon$$
$$\lvert x_{n} - 10 \rvert < \epsilon$$
Therefore,
$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists M > 0 \text{ such that } \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, n > M \implies \lvert x_{n} - 10 \rvert < \epsilon$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(x_{n}) = 10$$
That's all cool and all, but how do I do this with limit theorems? I assume the solution is way easier than I'm making it.

$L$ must satisfy $L= {1 \over 2} (L +{100 \over L})$. It tells you to assume the limit exists. If you want to pursue it more, look at the Newton update for solving $x^2 = 100$.

For large $n$ we have that $x_n \approx x_{n+1} \approx L$. Using this, we can write:
$$ L = \frac{1}{2}(L+\frac{100}{L}) $$
Solving this for $L$ we get:
$$ 2L^2 = L^2 + 100 $$
$$ L^2 = 100 $$
We then get two possible values for $L$: $10$ and $-10$. If it is not intuitive yet which one our series will converge to i will continue.
It is now up to us to decide which one the series converges to based on $x_1$. I will start by noting $x_1>0$. From there we also know that $100/x_1>0$. Since we are adding these we get that $x_2$ will be positive. We can continue doing this to see that as long as $x_n$ is positive $x_{n+1}$ will also be positive. Therefore our series will end up being positive so $L=10$. This technique is called induction which is an interesting topic in itself so I will point you to this Wikipedia page if you want to read more about it.

I get the usage of the approximation involving large n here but I don't see how to jump from there to solving $L = f(L)$. Especially since the approximation sign has no rigorous definition.

$L= f(L)$ are what I call equilibrium points. In other words, they will not move when applying $f$. We then find these equilibrium points to be around $\pm 10$. Our function is continuous everywhere except zero, but more specifically, at these equilibrium points. Then using the epsilon-delta definition of continuity, we have that if $x$ is close to $L$ (formally, $|x-L|<\delta$), then $f(x)$ will be close to $f(L)$ ($|f(x)-f(L)|<\epsilon$, for appropriate $\delta$ and $\epsilon$). And then we can make these arbitrarily small. We are also told a limit does exist so this eases some of the rigor.

Since, in comments, @copper.hat gave the simplest approach, let us go one step further.
Making the problem more general
$$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(x_n + \frac{a}{x_n}\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad x_1=a~>0$$ Looking at the first terms, remembering multiple angle formulae and using the kind of methods described in this paper,
$$x_n=\sqrt{a}\, \coth \Big(2^{n-1} \coth^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)\Big)$$ whose limit is $\sqrt a$.
